# Can a refrigirator become Tameh if Pushed by a Niddah?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

If a refrigerator was given tumah by a niddah. How do you purify it?

Comment: Can a refrigerator become impure? It's not too big?

Comment: @DoubleAA what's the shiur, please?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a metal kli, so it can become tamei regardless of its size (Rambam, Kelim 1:9).

Comment: @Shalom contains 40 seah, but Meir correctly notes the rule doesn't apply to metal keilim. (I'm not entirely sure what a fridge counts as material wise. Plus it's plugged in so maybe mechubbar lekarka?)

Comment: cc @meir ^^^^^^

Comment: @meir so how do you purify it? Do I take it into the shower? What about the food inside? Is the food and drink inside also tameeh?

Comment: @IsraelB. Utensils that became impure by anything other than contact with a dead body are purified by dipping in a mikva (except earthenware vessels which can't be purified).

Comment: @DoubleAA Everyone is gonna be all to happy when I arrive to the mikve with my fridge. Can a niddah pass tumah by pushing something?

Comment: Why are you specifically asking about a Niddah, and by pushing?

Comment: This reminds me of https://xyproblem.info